# emberjs view with raphael or d3

Tags: raphael, ember.js, d3.js

I would like to render an ember.js view using either [raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) or [d3.js](http://d3js.org/). My understanding is that [it is possible to do this](http://corner.squareup.com/2012/04/building-analytics.html), but I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work after reading all the docs and googling around. Any suggestions?

A hello world example would be ideal to at least get me started on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a blog post by Johannes Fahrenkrug, using `Raphael.js` with `Sproutcore 2.0` http://blog.sproutcore.com/using-raphael-js-with-sproutcore-2-0/. The code is hosted at https://github.com/jfahrenkrug/sproutcore-raphael.

Since Ember.js kinda evolved from Sproutcore 2.0, it shouldn't be to much work to use the existing code. Iv'e ported the excellent example by Johannes to Ember.js and created a JSFiddle, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/BHYgQ/. You should definitely check out the project on GitHub.

My ported example is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/pangratz/ember-raphael) and can be seen live at http://pangratz.github.com/ember-raphael.

---

As for D3, you can take a look at Alex Rothenberg's post [Combining D3 and Ember to Build Interactive Maps](http://www.alexrothenberg.com/2012/05/30/interactive-maps-with-d3-and-ember.html).

Comment: Cheers! The fiddle was outdated, I fixed it up so that the external resources load correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/BHYgQ/34/

Answer (score 0):

I ported DC.js Crossfilter + D3 Charts over to Ember Components https://github.com/andrewreedy/ember-dc