# Rendering D3 graph in an Ember.js app

Tags: ember.js, d3.js

I am using D3.js force layout to draw a nodes-and-links graph based on the data from ember.js models.  I have an `App.Device` model and an `App.Interface` model (network devices and network interfaces), so I just need to `App.Device.find()` and `App.Interface.find()` and iterate over the returned data in order to produce the nodes/links to render.

Except, not so fast.  Everything in Ember is asynchronous.  I looked at [Access model association from view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614501/access-model-association-from-view) -- but using an observer means it only redraws when the model changes... not when the route is navigated to.  I also can't figure out how to have a model that is the result of two finds, and thus can only have the observer on one of my two results.

I also found [emberjs view with raphael or d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738965/emberjs-view-with-raphael-or-d3) -- but all the links over there seem to be dead / out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the easiest way to do what I was trying to do was to create a pseudo compound model inside the route:

```
App.NetworkmapRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
      return Ember.Object.create({
         devices: App.Device.find(),
         interfaces: App.Interface.find()
      });
   }
});
```

Then I can create computed properties on the controller (which *must* be an `ObjectController`) and use an observer in the view that observes those controller properties and does the drawing.  This seems to be working.